# How to dynamically add new data into Memory Proxy Store in Extjs 6.5.2?

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs sencha treestore for storing data. I want to append new records dynamically after setting the Memory Proxy Store. How can I do that?

Here's the code for my store:

```
Ext.define('Test.store.TreeBufferStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

alias: 'store.TreeBufferStore',
storeId:'TreeBufferStore',
parentIdProperty: 'parentId',
autoSync:true,
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
```

});

Here's the code for my controller:

```
Ext.define('Test.controller.login.LoginController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.login',

someButtonClick: function () {

    var treeBufferStore = Ext.getStore('TreeBufferStore');
    var node = [{
        "id": '0',
        "parentId": null,
        "text": "Hello",
        "leaf": record.length == 0 ? true : false
    }];
    treeBufferStore.getProxy().setData(node);// <== It works well 
   console.log(treeBufferStore.getProxy().getData());

   if(num === 1) {
       var childnode = {
           "id": '1',
           "parentId": '0',
           "text": 'World',
           "leaf": true
       };
       treeBufferStore.getProxy().getData().add(childnode); // <== It can not work,how can I do for this?
   }
    treeBufferStore.load();
}
```

});

I get error messages for treeBufferStore.getProxy().getData().add() is not a function. 
If any one know how to fix it.Please help me!

Thanks in advance, Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> treeBufferStore.getProxy().getData().add it don't have method add. it will return the array of all data in store.

In ExtJs docs provide method to add data in store using 2 method **store.setRoot()** or **store.add()**. You can refer [ExtJs docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/modern/Ext.data.TreeStore.html#method-setRoot)

I have create small demo to show you, how it work. [Sencha fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26nk)

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    autoSync: true,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
var objectData = {
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
        text: 'detention',
        leaf: true
    }, {
        text: 'homework',
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: 'book report',
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: 'algebra',
            leaf: true
        }]
    }, {
        text: 'buy lottery tickets',
        leaf: true
    }]
};
store.setRoot(objectData);
```